# Sync deleted files from Dropbox on Android

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using the Core API on Android to sync folders in Dropbox to a local folder.

I managed to list the files, download them, save revision on a database all working pretty well.

But I forgot I need to delete the local files that were deleted in Dropbox, so I figured I could check the `isDeleted` property on an [`Entry`](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1-docs/index.html). But the way I do is get the list of files in `contents` for the folder `Entry` but that does not return older files that were deleted.

How can I get the deleted files from Dropbox, to check if they still exist locally? I would not like to have to cross check if the files in my folder exist on Dropbox, only from Dropbox to my folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `include_deleted` parameter on the /metadata HTTP endpoint, but this isn't implemented in the [Android Core SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android)'s [metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#metadata(java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String)) method. A better overall solution is to use [delta](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#delta(java.lang.String)) anyway. This is an efficient way to keep your local state up to date with the Dropbox server state, and it will indicate to you when and what items have been deleted so you can remove them from your local state.

Comment: Is there any code example on how to use delta? I'll make sure to accept your answer once I figure it out ^^

Comment: Ok so I think I managed to get the info from `DeltaPage<Entry>` , the entry from a file I had deleted is there but `isDeleted` comes false =/

Comment: Have you processed all the delta entries? You may be looking at an earlier one, while there is a later one with null metadata, meaning the file doesn't exist on Dropbox anymore: https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.DeltaEntry.html You can find more documentation here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/69/efficiently-enumerating-dropbox-with-delta